# Does "had have been" exist?

Tags: present-tense, past-perfect

Does "had have been" exist and what tense is it?

> I **had have seen** her

Comment: Perhaps the contraction "I'd have seen her" is confusing: that contracts ***would,*** not *had*.

Comment: No, but you can have had beans :)

Comment: He had to have been here, because I can smell those beans! :)

Comment: And you can have been had.

Comment: This is pretty much a variant of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138790/i-have-had-had-a-question perhaps a close enough variant to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

No: as an auxillary verb *have* (and so *had*) takes the past participle.

So "I have see her" is wrong and so is "I had have seen her".

You also cannot pile up *have* as auxiliary verbs.  So while "I have had breakfast" is correct, "I have had seen her" would also be wrong.

Comment: You can pile up a lot of auxiliary verbs if you're clever. "None of the dogs I have had have had guard dog training".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *"[None of the dogs (that) I have had] have had guard dog training"* involves a relative clause that is part of the subject. So your two pairs of "have had" are in two different clauses.

Answer (score 2):

The [past perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) is formed with the auxiliary, have, in the past simple and the main verb in the past participle.

> I had seen her

The [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) is formed with the auxiliary have in the present simple and again, the main verb in the past participle

> I have seen her

Therefore the sentence below

> I had have seen her

is a mixture of two [perfect aspect](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/perfectterm.htm) constructions and I would consider it to be ungrammatical. Native speakers and non-natives would be confused reading or hearing that expression because the time reference is very unclear.

When did you see her? Recently (*present perfect*)? Or did you see her *before* another event in the past (*past perfect*)?

Comment: "I wouldn't know if she was a good therapist; none of the patients *I had have seen her*."

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Then you would need a comma after *had*. None of the patients I had, have seen her.

Comment: I think it's unreadable with a comma there. You can find dozens of similar constructions with no comma and I can't find a single one with it. "The professors I had have been helpful." "None of the books I had have been misplaced." And so on.

Comment: The section with "I have had have been" etc. are grammatical but they are part of a longer sentence. *Had* in the sentence refers to possession, while the remaining clause is in the present perfect. I am only commenting on what the OP has provided. Feel free to answer and explain why the sentence "I had have seen her" is acceptable! :)

Comment: As I read the OP's question, he's looking for a way to use "had have been" and giving just one example of a possible way. I don't think he's asking whether that particular sentence is grammatical. (But it's unclear.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if you look at the editing history, but it was a typo, I believe the OP is a non-native speaker.

Comment: If the question really is just "Can you say 'I had have seen her'." then it doesn't belong here. (Perhaps on ell.)

Comment: At last. Somebody adding support from an 'authority'. +1 At [English Forums](http://www.englishforums.com/English/HadBeenAndWouldHaveBeen/njvxp/post.htm) is: For me, the only correct form is "if I had been able", though you will find people who insist that "if I would have been able" or even "if I had've been able" or "if I had of been able" or "if I would of been able" is correct. // and: "If Ida been there I woulda helped you," (the latter with a slang tag). There are 13 million Google hits for "If I had have been", perhaps indicating that the 'rules' are less permanent than some would like.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz *"[[none of the patients [(that) I had] have seen her"* involves a relative clause that is part of the subject -- the main clause is headed by "have".

Answer (score 0):

This technically incorrect usage is quite common in English speaking countries now. Often it indicates a mixup between a conditional present and past perfect. For example: "If the weather had been better, we could have played." "If the weather would have been better, we could have played." What often comes out in spoken English is "If the weather had've been better we could've played." "had" is replacing "would" in the same way that "of" replaces "have" in conditional sentences (eg "I would of gone to work if my car hadn't broken down"). This is just language in evolution.

Comment: You should some cite reliable sources for what you assert, especially in your first sentence. In my experience,   it's not at all common. Writing *would of* for *would've* is somewhat common  but it is also sometimes done on purpose to represent colloquial speech.

Comment: It is very familiar to me in England (colloquially). See perhaps https://journals.openedition.org/anglophonia/790 for an analysis. And a detailed analysis from Australia: https://theaussieenglishpodcast.com/pronunciation-hadve-hadah-dve-dah/ . I think Daniel is right in connecting it with "would". "Would" and "Had" both get contracted to "’d" and then a "would have" gets uncontracted into a "had have".

Answer (score -1):

I cannot think of a context where that would be correct usage.

Comment: How about, "The best days I have ever *had have been* spent with my father".

Comment: I would write: The best days I have ever had *were* spent with my father.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not saying you have to use "had have been", just that you can, and it's perfectly fluent and understandable. In any event, you changed the tense, and thus the meaning (I'm describing the effect of the process of spending them, you're describing the effect of the fact that they were spent).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Your example *"[The best days (that) I have ever had] have been spent with my father"* also involves a relative clause that is part of the subject. Also, there's *"What it was was bad"*.